# Data lost while encoding PHP array into JSON formatted data

Tags: php, json

I have some data stored in a MySQL table and I get that out with PDO. The function puts the result of the query into an array and all the fields are present:

```
  Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [nome] => Oggetto 1 [descr] => Questa è la favolosa descrizione dell'oggetto 1 [prezzo] => 50.00 [imgpath] => dummy.jpg [url] => http://localhost/ [cat] => 1 [avail] => 1 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [nome] => Oggetto 2 [descr] => Questa è la favolosa descrizione dell'oggetto 2 [prezzo] => 45.00 [imgpath] => dummy.jpg [url] => http://localhost/ [cat] => 1 [avail] => 1 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [nome] => Oggetto 3 [descr] => Questa è la meravigliosa descrizione dell'oggetto 3 [prezzo] => 120.00 [imgpath] => dummy.jpg [url] => http://localhost/ [cat] => 3 [avail] => 1 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [id] => 4 [nome] => Oggetto 4 [descr] => Questa è la meravigliosa descrizione dell'oggetto 4 [prezzo] => 200.00 [imgpath] => dummy.jpg [url] => http://localhost [cat] => 2 [avail] => 1 ) 
    [4] => Array ( [id] => 5 [nome] => Oggetto 5 [descr] => Questa è la fantasiosa descrizione dell'oggetto 5 [prezzo] => [imgpath] => dummy.jpg [url] => http://locahost [cat] => 4 [avail] => 1 ) )
```

The thing is I need a json formatted data response so I use the `json_encode` function to turn the PHP array into JSON formatted data, but as you can see from the following output the field `descr` has gone missing and I can't figure out why:

```
    [
      {"id":"1","nome":"Oggetto 1","descr":null,"prezzo":"50.00","imgpath":"dummy.jpg","url":"http:\/\/localhost\/","cat":"1","avail":"1"},
      {"id":"2","nome":"Oggetto 2","descr":null,"prezzo":"45.00","imgpath":"dummy.jpg","url":"http:\/\/localhost\/","cat":"1","avail":"1"},
      {"id":"3","nome":"Oggetto 3","descr":null,"prezzo":"120.00","imgpath":"dummy.jpg","url":"http:\/\/localhost\/","cat":"3","avail":"1"},
      {"id":"4","nome":"Oggetto 4","descr":null,"prezzo":"200.00","imgpath":"dummy.jpg","url":"http:\/\/localhost","cat":"2","avail":"1"},
      {"id":"5","nome":"Oggetto 5","descr":null,"prezzo":null,"imgpath":"dummy.jpg","url":"http:\/\/locahost","cat":"4","avail":"1"}
    ]
```

can this be due to the fact I have declared the `desc` as text field in the table? If so how do I make sure the data in that field doesn't get lost while passing from PHP array to JSON formatted data?

Comment: Please pretty-print your output, it's hard to read on just one line.

Comment: @str hopefully it's more readable now!

Comment: `json_encode` expects an unicode string, but a string in a different encoding may be an invalid unicode string because of the accented characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `descr` field values, the character `è` is not executable character in JSON, so use `htmlentities($_POST[descr])` before getting array results.

**Ex:**

```
<?php
    $a = htmlentities("Questa è la favolosa descrizione dell'oggetto 1");
    $arr = array('a' => $a);

    echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

**Result is,**

```
{"a":"Questa è la favolosa descrizione dell'oggetto 1"}
```

http://codepad.org/M2P8mnR8

**NOTE:**
 you can use UTF8 to encode those chracters using MYSQL itself

Answer (score 1):

Because the [descr] string contains extended characters, you may need to encode it with something like PHP's *htmlentities* function.